# UICollectionViewCell containing a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView which has cells that in turn also contain a little 3-paged CollectionView themselves.

That way, the user can scroll in the main view and also swipe the little cells left and right.

My problem is that I want these cells to be initialized in a way that their CollectionView always shows the center item (item 1) as default.

When the main view loads, I do this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    for cell in self.CollectionView.visibleCells {
        (cell as! PersonCell).CollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1), at: [], animated: false)
    }
    self.CollectionView.alpha = 1
}
```

Which works fine, but when I scroll the main CollectionView down, of course new cells are initialized and they all show their item 0 in their own CollectionView.
What would be a good solution for this?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Maybe make a subclass of UICollectionViewCell with the custom scrolling call in the init method.

Comment: I actually already use a subclass! I'll post as an answer what I did and what seems to work. Tell me what you think!

Comment: Nope, what you suggested doesn't work unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, but not sure if 100% "correct" or always working:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as? PersonCell)?.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1), at: [], animated: false)
}
```